# In a mongodb database, how do I find() and filter out any subdocuments?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

If I have a mongodb database, is it possible to:

`db.mydb.find(...)`

Such that the result will filter out any subdocuments which may be present, without knowing what they are in advance?

For example, if I had:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "george", "address" : { "street" : "101 example way", "city" : "tutorial", "state" : "CA" }, "other thing" : "thing value" }
```

What arguments could I pass to find() that would result in getting:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "george", "other thing" : "thing value" }
```

*without* having to specify:

```
db.mydbl.find( {}, { "address" : 0} )
```

Does a method to suppress all subdocuments exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dynamically remove any nested objects without specifying any existing keys, you can achieve that using aggregation framework:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            keysAndValues: {
                $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            keysAndValues: {
              $filter: {
                 input: "$keysAndValues",
                 as: "kvPair",
                 cond: { $ne: [ { $type: "$$kvPair.v" }, "object" ] }
              }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$keysAndValues" }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically the idea is quite simple: we want to transform a document into a list of key value pairs using ([$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)). Then we can filter out those key-value pairs where value is of [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) `"object"`. In last step we can transform our array back to an object using [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm looking at the objectToArray operator, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm using the example on the objectToArray documentation page, but directly copying and pasting the inventory example to just test it, I get `"errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$objectToArray'"`  Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

Comment: It was introduced in v 3.6 so I think you need to upgrade your db server if it's possible. I'm afraid that's the only way of reading keys and values dynamically

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much!